# Text-to-speech on iOS (robovm) with libgdx

Tags: ios, libgdx, text-to-speech, robovm

I'm trying to develop an app on iOS with libgdx. I want to use the text-to-speech but I can't find anything about that.

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Sorry, I didn't realise that you wasn't developing using a native SDK. This probably wouldn't work with that.

---

**If you are able to include native code:**

Starting from iOS 7 you could use `AVSpeechUtterance` and `AVSpeechSynthesizer` to achieve this.

[See here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechUtterance_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.

Simple Example (via [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/avspeechsynthesizer/)):

```
NSString *string = @"Hello, World!";
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:string];
utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-US"];

AVSpeechSynthesizer *speechSynthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
[speechSynthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```